# How to put loader used with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, loader

I have made an animation whose use would be to act like a loading animation, for example when the page is loading, when user clicks on a button, submits a form, etc. In this example, in the following code I would like that when the users clicks on the button, the page redirects to this loading animation, and then after the animation has ended, after few seconds it opens up a new file, that is the page for the input the user has typed in. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="text.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text">
    <button>Click</button>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){


            $('input').keyup(function(){
                if($('input').val() === 'New York'){
                    $('button').click(function(){
                        window.location.href = "newyork.html";
                    });
                } else if($('input').val() === 'New Jersey'){
                    $('button').click(function(){
                        window.location.href = "newjersey.html";
                    });
                }
            });

        });


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, I used jQuery. When user clicks on the button, I want that page redirects the user to the specific page which would be the result of what the user has inputted. In this example, if user typed New York in the input, I would like that the page redirects to newyork.html file. But, before it does that, I would first make that loading animation, and then this new file to appear. Here's the code for the loader:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
   body{
            background-color: rgba(60, 70, 255, 0.3);
        }
  .boat img{
                width: 90px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                right: 20%;
                animation: boat 3s 1s infinite ease;
                z-index: 10;
            }

            @keyframes boat{
            from{right: 20%;}
            to{right: 65%;}
            }
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>

     <div class="boat">
        <img src="http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/128-128-d8d329b704d34cf035a25811e32ba733-boat.png">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I made three separate files, the loader, the input page and the output page.

Comment: Why do you want the loader to be a separate page?

Comment: Okay, It doesnt have to be...

Comment: In general, the approach is to have a loading panel, which is invisible normally, but is shown while in a loading state, filling the whole viewport. I advise you to adopt this approach, because if the loader is a different page and your network is down, then even the loader will not be shown.